# Meaning of ～なさいということらしい in this context

Tags: meaning

> わたしは畳の上で正座したが、僧侶の指示で[結跏趺坐]{けっかふざ}に組み直した。[胡座]{あぐら}から両方の足の甲を腿の上に載せるポーズである。**瞑想をして、心を落ち着けなさいということらしい**。

What does the last part mean? Does it mean "Apparently (by telling me to sit in the lotus position) the monk was telling me to meditate and calm my heart"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. ～ということらしい roughly translates to "It seems to mean ～", and "瞑想をして心を落ち着けなさい" is the quote, i.e., what the narrator thought the monk was saying.